# What is difference between TypeScript and AtScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, atscript

As my knowledge TypeScript Developed by Microsoft and Used for dynamically generate JavaScript.

I want know that What is difference between TypeScript and AtScript. Which one is better to learn for JavaScript programmer.

Comment: Have you read the tooltips of both tags? atscript is now a part of typescript.

Comment: [AtScript is gone - long live TypeScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/03/05/angular-2-0-built-on-typescript.aspx)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AtScript

Comment: @mfeineis -- *"AtScript is gone"* -- Thank you, exactly the clarification I was looking for.

Answer (score 17):

Rather than create another new programming language—Google has already done that with Dart—AtScript is designed to run on top of not only ECMAScript 5 and the upcoming ECMAScript 6, but atop Microsoft’s superset TypeScript language as well. The goal of AtScript is to make type annotation data available at runtime, also known as type introspection, in an effort to enhance JavaScript with type, field and metadata annotations.
[image]
References

- http://sdtimes.com/atscript-googles-new-superset-javascript-runtime/
- http://techcrunch.com/2015/03/05/microsoft-and-google-collaborate-on-typescript-hell-has-not-frozen-over-yet

Comment: AtScript+TypeScript =Angular 2 ?

Comment: Angular has been using its own AtScript superset of Microsoft’s TypeScript for a while now.  Angular 2 will be written in TypeScript and developers will be able to write their Angular 2 applications in this language,too.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it the intention was [that ATScript will be a superset of TypeScript](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11YUzC-1d0V1-Q3V0fQ7KSit97HnZoKVygDxpWzEYW0U/edit) which will add some additional features around reflection and metadata.

It was [recently announced](http://sdtimes.com/google-microsoft-combine-typescript-atscript-angular-2/) that [google and microsoft have been working together](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2015/03/05/typescript-lt-3-angular.aspx) and that ATScript and Typescript will be merged moving forward.